# Close spring on initialization

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

So I have a Spring app running on Tomcat. While deploying initialization I sometimes may run into some errors (i.e. that some JDNI value is not found or that the app is not able to connect to some service). So when this happen I throw and exception and catch it in the @Configuration file. In the catch block I try to close the app with a System.exit(-1). But it doesn't seem to be the right way to do it. Cause Intellij is no capable or turning off the server, I even have seen that resources are not released till server is OFF.

I have also tried:

```
@Autowired
public ApplicationContext application context
@Bean
public IServerDataCache serverDataCache() {
    try {
        return new ServerDataCache(args);
    } catch(InitializationError initializationError) {
        log.error("Unable to load configuration for Server Data Cache. Closing application.");
        System.exit(1); OR SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext)
    }
    return null;
}
```

Both  System.exit(1); OR SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext) seem to have the same effect. Any idea of a better way to enforce application finalization.

BTW it is a spring boot application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let your `@Bean` method throw the exception. It will be caught by the container and it'll then take care of tidying things up.

Comment: Just to clarify, the suggestion is something like this:

    @Bean
    public IServerDataCache serverDataCache() throws InitializationError {
      return new ServerDataCache(args);
    }

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Although Andy Wilkinson's answer is correct, I'd just like to add that, since you're running your application on Tomcat (and not an **embedded** Tomcat), the Tomcat server **doesn't** shutdown when the application fails to start.
This happens by design, since Tomcat is, like all JavaEE containers, meant to run several applications at once.

If you want the whole process to stop when the application fails, you need to switch to using an embedded container.